# Unable to fetch nvarchar type data with where clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause, between

```
string constr = Properties.Settings.Default.Subject_1ConnectionString;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Subject_Title WHERE Date BETWEEN @hello and @hello1 ", conn);

// com.Parameters.Add("@hello", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
// com.Parameters.Add("@hello1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;

com.Parameters.Add("@hello", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
com.Parameters["@hello"].Value = textBox1.Text;

com.Parameters.Add("@hello1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
com.Parameters["@hello1"].Value = textBox2.Text;

// com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hello", textBox1.Text);
// com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hello1", textBox2.Text);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Subject_title");

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    this.labeltext = this.labeltext + " " + ds.Tables["Subject_Title"].Rows[i]["Date"].ToString();
    this.labeltext = this.labeltext + " " + ds.Tables["Subject_Title"].Rows[i]["Subject"].ToString();
    this.labeltext = this.labeltext + " ";
}

this.label1.Text = this.labeltext;
```

Here I'm not getting any data from the database

`Date` is my column name with a `nvarchar` type, and `Subject` is another column of type `text`.

Pls anyone solve my problem

Comment: you can use single quotes instead of double quotes,btw is your date type is `datetime`?

Comment: no i have kept it as nvarchar

Comment: Then you will never end to have problems with that field, change it as soon as possible to a real datetime field

Comment: still its not fetching any data

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes! If `date` (really bad column name, btw!) is a `NVARCHAR`, you **CANNOT** use `BETWEEN` to look at it as a date! Seriuosly - you have to use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` for your date-related columns!!

Comment: u r right @marc_s but the thing is i m fetching some hardcoded data from sourcefile of a website in which they are stating dates in form of 1/01/14  or 1/1/14. . means such format is nit compartible with the type data of sql. .thats y i have used nvarchar

Comment: For date-related elements, **DON'T USE** `nvarchar` !

Comment: You should check your date format,by Default date format is 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use:
Con.Open();
Con.Close();

But if I were you I would have written this code like this:

```
    string constr = Properties.Settings.Default.Subject_1ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Subject_Title WHERE Date BETWEEN \"01-03-14\" and \"01-04-14\" ", conn);

    conn.Open();       
    SqlDataReader reader =com.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.read()){

    this.labeltext += " " + reader.GetString(0);       //Use column ordinal for Date
    this.labeltext += " " + reader.GetString(1)+" ";   //Use column ordinal for Subject
    }
    conn.Close()
    this.label1.Text = this.labeltext;
```

Comment: OK, try the code I provided. Using da.Fill will bring all the data to memory which is a waste of resources in your case. Using a reader.Read() will only get one record at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to come up with a better code base for you.

You need to:

- use **more meaningful** names! Parameters like `hello` and `hello1` aren't very useful to someone reading your code.... also: don't name your columns with reserved keywords like `Date` - again: use something more meaningful to your context
- if you want to use date-related methods, you must use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(N)` datatypes. If you have stored your data as `nvarchar` - you must convert it first to a `DATE`
- please always put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using(...) { .. }` blocks to ensure proper and speedy disposal
- if you only need a single `DataTable` - just instantiate a `DataTable` and fill it - don't use the unnecessary additional overhead of a `DataSet` - that's just wasted resources...

Code:

```
string constr = Properties.Settings.Default.Subject_1ConnectionString;

// if you only need one single data table - use a DataTable - not a DataSet !
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// *ALWAYS* put your SqlConnection and SqlCommand into using() blocks!
// also - if you want to use BETWEEN, you *MUST* use DATE!
// also: don't call your column "date" - that's a SQL Server reserved keyword! Use a more meaningful name 
// like "DateCreated" or "DateLastUpdated" or something
// and please also use more meaningful parameter names - "hello" and "hello1" is very confusing and not clear!!
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Subject_Title WHERE CAST(DateCreated AS DATE) BETWEEN @start and @end ", conn))
{
   // add parameters as DATE type!
   com.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.Date);
   com.Parameters["@start"].Value = DateTime.Parse(textBox1.Text).Date;

   com.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.Date);
   com.Parameters["@end"].Value = DateTime.Parse(textBox2.Text).Date;

   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

   da.Fill(dt);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    this.labeltext = this.labeltext + " " + dt.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString();
    this.labeltext = this.labeltext + " " + ds.Rows[i]["Subject"].ToString();
    this.labeltext = this.labeltext + " ";
}

this.label1.Text = this.labeltext;
```

Comment: giving error at da.fill(dt,"subject_tittle")   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(System.Data.DataTable, System.Data.IDataReader)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Date.Parse. . Cannot find Date type. .

Comment: @user3551226: sorry, got mixed up between the T-SQL and .NET datatypes; .NET only has `DateTime` - so it has to be `DateTime.Parse(...)` and then use the `.Date` property on the result to get just the date (no time portion) from the value provided